# python module 'spidev' not found

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

python software from pi plates doesn't work with python 3.10.
One specific is that 'import spidev' cannot find spidev module.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `Any suggestions` Install it? and make sure it's installed for Python 3. Anyway, this is not Pi specific

Comment: What OS? Why (and how) did you install python3.10?